# How to terminate login screen to Wolfram cloud without rebooting Mathematica itself?

Tags: front-end, wolfram-cloud

I wanted to try an example here [NFourierTransform](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NFourierTransform), so copied the example and pasted it into my notebook in my PC.

I get a popup windows asking me to login to the Wolfram cloud. I did not want to do this at this time (I do not even know if I have an account there, I need to check). So I clicked cancel. But it will not go away.

I am also not able to use any other notebook and do anything with Mathematica now.

This does not sound right. One should be able to cancel a login screen without being stuck. Is this really how it is supposed to work? Any workaround?

This is Mathematica v 12 on windows 10 professional 64 bit OS.

[image]

Notice if you try it, make sure to SAVE all your notebooks, as there is no way out unless you login to the cloud first. I lost somework myself due to this, since only option I found is to terminate the whole Mathematica process from window.

Also killing the kernel process from windows does not help. I had to terminate the whole Mathematica process. Which tells me this is a front end problem.

Comment: Can you not go to Evaluation > Quit Kernel when this happens?

Comment: @b3m2a1 no. That is the whole point. I can't do anything. Since the front end was locked completely. I can add this to the movie if you give me a minute.

Comment: Hm... seems to be a Windows issue. No problems quitting it on Mac. One sad thing about that chunk of code you tried to execute being the cause of the crash: it's literally just a wrapper on ``FourierSeries`NFourierTransform`` which is actually built in and doesn't need the cloud.

Comment: @b3m2a1 fyi, I've just updated the movie. As you can see not possible to do what you said, since kernel is busy with the pop-up window and will not give me time to do anything else.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Have you asked WRI?